# Scala error: value <FUNCTION_NAME> is not a member of object <OBJECT_NAME>

Tags: scala, function, methods

**LATER EDIT:**

- Related questions:

[Why are Scala class methods not first-class citizens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495571/why-are-scala-class-methods-not-first-class-citizens?rq=1)

[Motivation for Scala underscore in terms of formal language theory and good style?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25763401/4511978)

Usage of the `_` wildcard, or *placeholder syntax*: [Scala placeholder syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260367/scala-placeholder-syntax)

- In this question I was trying to achieve a more compact syntax, and the solution involved the so-called *placeholder syntax*. This viewpoint is reinforced in Jason Swartz's [Learning Scala](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-scala/9781449368814/), page 74:

> Placeholder syntax is especially helpful when working with data structures and collections. Many of the core sorting, filtering, and other data structure methods tend to use
>   first-class functions, and placeholder syntax reduces the amount of extra code required
>   to call these methods.

---

**QUESTION BODY**

I'm trying out Scala's support for first-order functions, and encountered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414994/how-to-pass-a-class-method-as-a-parameter-in-scala) problem, about passing methods as parameters. As far as I understood, the solution is to wrap the method with a (named or anonymous) first-order function. This worked for me:

```
def wrapperFn(s:String):String = s.reverse
```

`wrapperFn` can be now passed as parameter to other higher-order functions, or as value to other definitions like this one:

```
val otherGoodFn:(String=>String) = goodWrapperFn
```

So far so good. The problem came when I tried to mix both steps (avoiding the somewhat verbose use of the `s` parameter), and directly pass the method to a function-typed value, like this:

```
def errorFn:(String=>String) = String.reverse
```

Which throws the following error:

```
error: value reverse is not a member of object String
   def errorFn:(String=>String) = String.reverse
                                                ^
```

Which I don't understand, because this works as expected:

```
val s:String = "hello"
s.reverse
```

So apparently the method is a member of the instance, but not of the Object/Class(??) It seems that Scala handles the class and object lifetime in a very different way as Java does. So my question, now more concisely:

- **Is the error caused by some stupid mistake or is it indeed not allowed? And if not allowed, why?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.reverse` would be calling a static method (or a method on an `object` instead of a class in Scala terms).

You can do

```
def errorWrapperFn:(String=>String) = _.reverse
```

The underscore here allows you to access the method/function parameters without having to give them a name.

Comment: great, thanks. I guess the `_` wildcard is directly mapped to the type before the `=>` token?

Comment: Yes, the type of the unnamed parameters are inferred from the method signature here.

Comment: and here is how (I edited my post anyway): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260367/scala-placeholder-syntax